# Physics and Oil pipelines

Tags: thermodynamics, resource-recommendations, flow, geophysics, bernoulli-equation

Is there a concise source or reference that details the physics that one deals with in the construction and/or operation of an oil pipeline.

This is for a Project-based Learning Unit in HS Physics.

Comment: You'll probably find more coverage of this topic if you look in the fields of chemical engineering or civil engineering, rather than physics.

Comment: I would think mostly civil but it will be difficult to find something at high school level no matter the field.  Under f;ow assurance books reading the preface or foreword might let the potential reader decide if it will be understood enough.

Comment: Surely the project material will recommend some sources which are appropriate to your level. Why aren't you making use of this material, at least as a starting point?

Comment: You need to narrow the scope of your project.  Civil engineering will cover the construction of the pipeline.  Mechanical engineering will cover rotating equipment design (e.g., pumps).  Chemical engineering will cover fluid flow and process control.

Answer (score 1):

Flow assurance is the term you need to use for researching your project. Flow assurance programs are used these days.  What you ask for can be obtained but if you're asking for the actual metallurgy I'm not going to be very helpful.  If what you are wanting to know is how to select what pipe to use for whatever parameters I think I can.  It is a process and no company just uses one source.  Not to worry I can give you several that should be more than enough for a high school project.  Let me just lightly go over the process first. The first step is to have a good idea of what the product will be like that you are transporting.  That means over the life of the project.  It can change a good deal as wells water out, H2s is suspect at some point, PH changes, new zones are perforated or different product directions are needed Etc.  Know the environment in all seasons, depths and altitudes, corrosion possibilities Etc.  What maximum, minimum pressures, any vacuums, lengths, slugging, vertical ups and downs and tees or bends you may encounter. If you are only doing something very simple and just looking for burst and collapse pressures the Halliburton Red book will suffice. I think you are looking for more than that though so try a book called the New Flow Assurance Book by Kashmir Johal. The later gets into the math, All that is mentioned and more from above and some operation. It is very comprehensive. You can just google flow assurance and find something less expensive but probably not as encompassing. You bit off a pretty big project for high school. Good luck.